# Unable to read parquet file using StreamingBody from S3 without holding in memory

Tags: python, boto3, parquet

I'm trying to read a parquet file from S3, and dump the contents of it on to a Kafka topic.

This isn't too difficult when you hold the entire file in memory, but for large files this isn't feasible.

```
# using .read() holds the entire file open in memory - not ideal
df = pd.read_parquet(s3_response['Body'].read(), columns=columns)
```

Instead, I'm trying to take advantage of file-like-objects in order to stream the parquet file.

My issue is that it seems that it's impossible to do this with Parquet, because Parquet encodes data in the footer of the file as well as the header.

Here's an example of my code:

```
session = boto3.session.Session()

s3_client = session.client(
    service_name='s3',
    endpoint_url=s3_url,
)

obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=key)

for line in obj['Body'].iter_lines():
    pq_file = io.BytesIO(line)
    df = pd.read_parquet(pq_file, columns=columns)
    # At this point I'd want to iterate over the DF rows
    # and send them to kafka
    print(df)
```

This results in the following error:
`OSError: Could not open parquet input source '<Buffer>': Invalid: Parquet magic bytes not found in footer. Either the file is corrupted or this is not a parquet file.`

Is it at all possible to do what I'm trying to do? Or due to the nature of parquet files is this impossible?

Comment: read_parquet on Pandas supports 's3://...' path.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html

Comment: @MasayukiTakahashi this loads the parquet file in to memory. My question is about how to consume it as a stream of data without loading the entire file in to memory

Comment: I understood your point. I think it is impossible to read as a chunk of a parquet file from S3 because Parquet is a binary file, not a line-by-line text file and it has metadata in a footer of a file. Reading a parquet file, it is necessary to read a footer section of it first.

Comment: Could you store the S3 object as a file in your local file system? If you can do that,  I think that Pandas can read a footer section of the local file first by file random access and read required columns only.